# Is there a way to set a default volume for different bluetooth connections?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, volume

I use my phone as my main audio player, with headphones, through my car, and through my speakers at home. When using it in the car I crank the audio on my phone to full volume and adjust volume through the cars audio system for a clearer sound. When at home I use the volume control on the phone and keep my speakers set to max for convenience. So if I go from my car to my house, the initial audio is near deafening.

This wouldn't be a problem except that once you connect to a bluetooth device it automatically starts audio playback, so I can't connect, decrease volume, then hit play. I'm also unable to decrease the volume without bluetooth being connected to something, and it's not convenient or easy to remember to turn down the volume every single time I get out of the car, just in case I play music at home before I drive again. I see two possible solutions but am unable to figure out how to accomplish either.

Solution 1 (preferred): Find a way to set a volume based on what device I'm connecting to.

Solution 2: Find a way to disable the auto-play function, but still allow for volume control once a device is connected.

Thanks for any help in advance y'all!

Answer (score 3):

There are two app in the Playstore you can try [A2DP Voume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=a2dp.Vol) and [Bluetooth Volume](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nightshadelabs.bluetoothvolume&hl=en).

A2DP is an app project hosted on [code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/)

Some features of A2DP:

- Captures car location automatically when device disconnects. Automatic car locator. (option)
- Each device can be independently configured.
- Automatically adjusts the media volume on Bluetooth connect and resets on Bluetooth disconnect. Automatically captures location information on disconnect so you can find where you left your car. [Read More](http://code.google.com/p/a2dpvolume/wiki/Manual)

[image: A2DP Screenshot]

<sub>Screenshot (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Bluetooth Volume app feature:

- This app is perfect for people that always adjusting the volume on their phone immediately after connecting to Bluetooth in the car. This app will do that for you automatically.
- Also has an option to launch a Car Home when you connect to Bluetooth.(You need to install Car Home app to use this feature).

So, I think one of the above apps is what you might be looking for.

Comment: Wow nice app @Lucky , it's definitely handy.